# How to set Span Context in current Context?

Tags: java, scala, open-telemetry

In `opentelemetery-api` version `0.8.0`, we used to set a new `SpanContext` in current `Context` via following code:

```scala
TracingContextUtils.currentContextWith(DefaultSpan.create(newSpanCtx))
```

However, in version `0.13.1`, both - `TracingContextUtils` and `DefaultSpan` are removed. Then how can I set a new `SpanContext` in the current `Context`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [opentelemetry-java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java) version [0.10.0 release notes](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/releases/tag/v0.10.0):

> - `TracingContextUtils` and `BaggageUtils` were removed from the public API. Instead, use the appropriate static methods on the `Span` and `Baggage` classes, or use methods on the `Context` itself.
> - `DefaultSpan` was removed from the public API. Instead, use `Span.wrap(spanContext)` if you need a non-functional span that propagates the trace context.

You can try something like:

```scala
val newSpanCtx: SpanContext = null
val span: Span = Span.wrap(newSpanCtx)
Context.current().`with`(span).makeCurrent()
```

Comment: You can't create your own ContextKey for the span. Always use our methods like "Span.current()"

Comment: @TomerShetah your solution is correct. I was using `TraceFlags` in `SpanContext` in the wrong way due to which my application was failing. After correcting it, the application worked seamlessly.

Comment: Wrap doesn't exist anymore in version 1.5.0 What is the alternative here?

Comment: @iamnicoj why would you say that? I see it at [Span.java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/api/all/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/api/trace/Span.java#L76). You can see [this scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/pbBExUDwRSWpYsvdWVehKg/1) example using 1.5.0 with `wrap`.

Comment: @TomerShetah I can't find it in the Java SDK

Comment: @iamnicoj please press the link I provided above.

Comment: Yes @TomerShetah, I was able to load an external SpanContext and create a Span in Java like this `Span childSpan = GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracer("foo").spanBuilder("bar")
            .setParent(Context.root().with((ImplicitContextKeyed)Span.wrap(parentContext)))
            .startSpan();`

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `scope` and calling the `makeCurrent` method?

```java
Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("my span").startSpan();
// put the span into the current Context
try (Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {
    // your use case
    ...
} catch (Throwable t) {
    span.setStatus(StatusCode.ERROR, "Change it to your error message");
} finally {
    span.end(); // closing the scope does not end the span, this has to be done manually
}
```

This is what the [quickstart](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md) also states.

Comment: How using `makeCurrent` of `span` is setting the `newSpanCtx`?

Comment: What is the use of making the span the current context?